# How to check if a string is a uniqueidentifier?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there an equivalent to IsDate or IsNumeric for uniqueidentifier (SQL Server)?
Or is there anything equivalent to (C#) TryParse?

Otherwise I'll have to write my own function, but I want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

The scenario I'm trying to cover is the following:

```
SELECT something FROM table WHERE IsUniqueidentifier(column) = 1
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.  You want to select all of the rows where the value for a certain column is a unique identifier?  What's the business scenario?  And if a column is meant to hold a uniqueidentifier, won't its value either be null or be, in fact, a uniqueidentifier?  What else could it be?

Comment: I'm creating databases using guids for names (Integration tests on build server). I wanted to list those databases (select * from sys.databases where IsUniqueidentifier(name))

Comment: Ah, got it -- you don't mean the uniqueidentifier datatype, just a string.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 makes this all much easier with [`TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, expression)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)

```
SELECT something
FROM   your_table
WHERE  TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, your_column) IS NOT NULL;
```

For prior versions of SQL Server, the existing answers miss a few points that mean they may either not match strings that SQL Server will in fact cast to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` without complaint or may still end up causing invalid cast errors.

SQL Server accepts GUIDs either wrapped in `{}` or without this.

Additionally it ignores extraneous characters at the end of the string. Both `SELECT CAST('{5D944516-98E6-44C5-849F-9C277833C01B}ssssssssss' as uniqueidentifier)` and `SELECT CAST('5D944516-98E6-44C5-849F-9C277833C01BXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' as uniqueidentifier)` succeed for instance.

Under most default collations the `LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9]'` will end up matching characters such as `À` or `Ë`

Finally if casting rows in a result to uniqueidentifier it is important to put the cast attempt in a case expression as the cast may occur before the rows are filtered by the `WHERE`.

So (borrowing [@r0d30b0y's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9577359/73226)) a slightly more robust version might be

```
;WITH T(C)
     AS (SELECT '5D944516-98E6-44C5-849F-9C277833C01B'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '{5D944516-98E6-44C5-849F-9C277833C01B}'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '5D944516-98E6-44C5-849F-9C277833C01BXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '{5D944516-98E6-44C5-849F-9C277833C01B}ssssssssss'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ÀD944516-98E6-44C5-849F-9C277833C01B'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'fish')
SELECT CASE
         WHEN C LIKE expression + '%'
               OR C LIKE '{' + expression + '}%' THEN CAST(C AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
       END
FROM   T
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN) C2(expression)
WHERE  C LIKE expression + '%'
        OR C LIKE '{' + expression + '}%'
```

Comment: Marked this answer as accepted since SQL Server 2012 address my original question quite well.

Comment: Just had one of those moments were seeing an answer on StackOverflow made my day. Somehow I'd not seen that TRY_CONVERT existed.

Comment: There is also [`TRY_CAST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx) if you do not need the style argument. [`TRY_PARSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) does not support `uniqueidentifier` so it does not need to be considered.

Comment: Upvoted for TRY_CONVERT.  Didn't know about such awesomeness.  Too bad the server I need this on is SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 74):

Not mine, found this online... thought i'd share.

```
SELECT 1 WHERE @StringToCompare LIKE 
       REPLACE('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]');
```

Comment: Nice one, however all those zeros could lead to a typo that's hard to track down :). IMHO, here is a slight improvement on your idea insuring the format of the empty UNIQUEIDENTIFIER is correct:


`SELECT 1 WHERE @StringToCompare LIKE Replace(Cast(Cast(0 AS BINARY) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]');`

Comment: Couldn't find the BigQuery SQL version, so thought I'd share mine here. `SELECT 1 WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(@StringToCompare, r'[0-9A-Fa-f]', '0') like '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'`

Comment: If you like to store it in a variable 

`DECLARE @IsGuid AS BIT = (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN '61d086f0-80e3-482f-ab6a-7279ab18cc3d' LIKE Replace(Cast(Cast(0 AS BINARY) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Answer (score 28):

```
SELECT something 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE column1 LIKE '[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]';
```

UPDATE:

...but I much prefer the approach in the answer by @r0d30b0y:

```
SELECT something 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE column1 LIKE REPLACE('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]');
```

Comment: You could turn this into a function, like pcofre suggests: `Create FUNCTION [dbo].[IsAGuid] (@Data varchar(50)) RETURNS bit WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
  BEGIN
   return case 
    when @Data like '[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]'
    then 1
    else 0 end
  END`

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of anything that you could use "out of the box" - you'll have to write this on your own, I'm afraid.

If you can: try to write this inside a C# library and deploy it into SQL Server as a SQL-CLR assembly - then you could use things like `Guid.TryParse()` which is certainly much easier to use than anything in T-SQL....

Answer (score 4):

Like to keep it simple.  A GUID has four - in it even, if is just a string

WHERE column like '%-%-%-%-%'

Comment: "I planted 100-200 forget-me-nots off-campus" is my favorite GUID

Answer (score 3):

A variant of r0d30b0y answer is to use PATINDEX to find within a string...

```
PATINDEX('%'+REPLACE('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]')+'%',@StringToCompare) > 0
```

Had to use to find Guids within a URL string..

HTH

Dave

Answer (score 2):

Though an older post, just a thought for a quick test ...

```
SELECT  [A].[INPUT],
        CAST([A].[INPUT] AS [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER])
FROM   (
            SELECT '5D944516-98E6-44C5-849F-9C277833C01B' Collate Latin1_General_100_BIN AS [INPUT]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '{5D944516-98E6-44C5-849F-9C277833C01B}'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '5D944516-98E6-44C5-849F-9C277833C01BXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '{5D944516-98E6-44C5-849F-9C277833C01B}ssssssssss'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'ÀD944516-98E6-44C5-849F-9C277833C01B'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'fish'
        ) [A]
WHERE   PATINDEX('[^0-9A-F-{}]%', [A].[INPUT]) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a function based on the concept of some earlier comments. This function is very fast.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IsGuid] (@input varchar(50))  
    RETURNS bit AS  
BEGIN

RETURN 
    case when @input like '[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]'
    then 1 else 0 end
END
GO

/* 
Usage: 

select [dbo].[IsGuid]('123') -- Returns 0
select [dbo].[IsGuid]('ebd8aebd-7ea3-439d-a7bc-e009dee0eae0') -- Returns 1

select * from SomeTable where dbo.IsGuid(TableField) = 0 -- Returns table with all non convertable items!

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @guid_string nvarchar(256) = 'ACE79678-61D1-46E6-93EC-893AD559CC78'

SELECT
    CASE WHEN @guid_string LIKE '________-____-____-____-____________'
    THEN CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, @guid_string)
    ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't check the characters are valid for a UUID but it checks the number of characters fit into where a UUID would fit... Underscore is a wildcard for "any character" so by using multiples of them, you can specify a length of the string. So the LIKE statement matches the pattern of a UUID. If it is not a UUID pattern then it will return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own UDF. This is a simple approximation to avoid the use of a SQL-CLR assembly.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.isuniqueidentifier (@ui varchar(50))  
RETURNS bit AS  
BEGIN

RETURN case when
    substring(@ui,9,1)='-' and
    substring(@ui,14,1)='-' and
    substring(@ui,19,1)='-' and
    substring(@ui,24,1)='-' and
    len(@ui) = 36 then 1 else 0 end

END
GO
```

You can then improve it to check if it´s just about HEX values.

Comment: Your function thinks that `------------------------------------` is a uniqueidentifier ;)

Comment: You could combine this with onedaywhen's answer: `Create FUNCTION [dbo].[IsAGuid] (@Data varchar(50)) RETURNS bit WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
  BEGIN
   return case 
    when @Data like '[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]'
    then 1
    else 0 end
  END`

Answer (score 0):

I use :

```
ISNULL(convert(nvarchar(50), userID), 'NULL') = 'NULL'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some Test users that were generated with AutoFixture, which uses GUIDs by default for generated fields. My FirstName fields for the users that I need to delete are GUIDs or uniqueidentifiers. That's how I ended up here.

I was able to cobble together some of your answers into this.

`SELECT UserId FROM [Membership].[UserInfo] Where TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, FirstName) is not null`

Answer (score 0):

Use RLIKE for MYSQL

```
SELECT 1 WHERE @StringToCompare
RLIKE REPLACE('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]');
```

Answer (score 0):

In a simplest scenario. When you sure that given string can`t contain 4 '-' signs.

```
SELECT * FROM City WHERE Name LIKE('%-%-%-%-%')
```

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery you can use

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(uuid, REPLACE('^00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000$', '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]'))
```