# Checking for Guid value in nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table which has a `NVARCHAR` column, which could contain a GUID or a string. This is a legacy table, so I can't change at this point of time.

I need to pick up the records with GUID. Any suggestions? I am using something like below as of now. Should making the the part after the like operator in the below query as UDF would impact performance or there is a better way?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE Column1 LIKE '[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]-[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]'
```

Comment: A tiny bit better (shorter) way would be to use `[0-9a-f]` or `[0-9A-F]` instead of `[0-9a-fA-F]`, if your `Column1` uses a `CI` collation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom function that tries to validate the data and detect it. I found some thing here for tsql:

http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/23114/best-way-to-check-that-a-stringvarchar-guid-is-val.html

Update:

Check marc_s's answer here too:

[How to check if a string is a uniqueidentifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649317/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-uniqueidentifier)

Comment: I am aware of the approach of making this a UDF. However, I am not sure of the performance implications of the same. I would measure the same in my case though. Just looking for a better approach here. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [sql clr function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx) and call [Guid.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx).