# tsql: xml node conversion errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, xml-parsing

What do I need to do in order to accommodate the incoming values on an Xml doc that are ultimately getting written as decimal(18,5), int, or unique identifiers that may have no data within the tags [although not NULL data--as i found the hard way], or text data in the tags. It seems like I solve for one problem, but create another!: -\  I am getting the errors: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '7800.00000' to data type int
and Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. How do I correct this?

Here's an example of the xml snippet coming in with data:

```
<Products>
  <Product>
      <AgreementId>2439</AgreementId>
      <Difference>0.00400</Difference>
      <DispatchedQuantity>7800.00000</DispatchedQuantity>
      <Freight>0.01560</Freight>
      <ProductGUID>d475165c-0031-41f6-ad44-cecb73dfd2de</ProductGUID>
      <ShortName>U_B5Not Specif_No2_U</ShortName>
    </Product>
  </Products
```

Here's the code to process it in a stored proc:

```
 SELECT
       l.OrderId,
       l.OrderLiftId,
       cast(n.x.value('AgreementId[1]', 'varchar(20)') as int),
       CAST(CASE WHEN n.x.value('Difference[1]', 'varchar(20)') = '' THEN 0 ELSE  COALESCE(n.x.value('Difference[1]', 'varchar(20)'), '0.00') END AS decimal(18,5)),
       CAST(CASE WHEN n.x.value('DispatchedQuantity[1]', 'varchar(20)') = '' THEN 0 ELSE  COALESCE(n.x.value('DispatchedQuantity[1]', 'varchar(20)'), '0.00') END AS decimal(18,5)),
       CAST(CASE WHEN n.x.value('Freight[1]', 'varchar(20)') = '' THEN 0 ELSE  COALESCE(n.x.value('Freight[1]', 'varchar(20)'), '0.00') END AS decimal(18,5)),
       cast(n.x.value('ProductGUID[1]', 'varchar(40)') as uniqueidentifier),
       n.x.value('ShortName[1]', 'varchar(100)')
  FROM @lines as l
   CROSS APPLY l.lineprods.nodes('/Products/Product') as n(x);
```

**UPDATE: This line --**

```
 CAST(CASE WHEN n.x.value('DispatchedQuantity[1]', 'varchar(20)') = '' THEN 0 ELSE  COALESCE(n.x.value('DispatchedQuantity[1]', 'varchar(20)'), '0.00') END AS decimal(18,5)),
```

needs to be changed to:

```
 CAST(CASE WHEN n.x.value('DispatchedQuantity[1]', 'varchar(20)') = '' THEN 0 ELSE  COALESCE(n.x.value('DispatchedQuantity[1]', 'decimal(18,5)'), '0.00') END AS decimal(18,5)),
```

to accommodate the non-numeric/non-nulls AND the first non-null that I hope is a decimal--it still may blowup if I get some other hokey value. Any suggestions on how to deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine the [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function would do the trick.

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(n.x.value('DispatchedQuantity[1]', 'varchar(max)')) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ... END
```

However, I don't understand why you are extracting the xml as varchar(20) before casting it to decimal. Once you've established the data is numeric you can simply use:

```
n.x.value('DispatchedQuantity[1]', ' decimal(18,5)')
```

The full SQL I used for testing:

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = '<Products>
              <Product>
                  <AgreementId>2439</AgreementId>
                  <Difference>0.00400</Difference>
                  <DispatchedQuantity>7800.00000</DispatchedQuantity>
                  <Freight>0.01560</Freight>
                  <ProductGUID>d475165c-0031-41f6-ad44-cecb73dfd2de</ProductGUID>
                  <ShortName>U_B5Not Specif_No2_U</ShortName>
                </Product>
                <Product>
                  <AgreementId>2439</AgreementId>
                  <Difference></Difference>
                  <DispatchedQuantity>INVALID NUMBER</DispatchedQuantity>
                  <Freight>INVALID FREIGHT</Freight>
                  <ProductGUID>INVALID GUID</ProductGUID>
                  <ShortName>U_B5Not Specif_No2_U</ShortName>
                </Product>
              </Products>'

SELECT  [AgreementId] = CAST(n.x.value('AgreementId[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS INT),
        [Difference] = CAST(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(n.x.value('Difference[1]', 'varchar(max)')) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE n.x.value('Difference[1]', 'decimal(18, 5)') END AS DECIMAL(18,5)),
        [DispatchedQuantity] = CAST(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(n.x.value('DispatchedQuantity[1]', 'varchar(max)')) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE n.x.value('DispatchedQuantity[1]', 'decimal(18, 5)') END AS DECIMAL(18,5)),
        [Freight] = CAST(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(n.x.value('Freight[1]', 'varchar(20)')) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE n.x.value('Freight[1]', ' decimal(18,5)') END AS DECIMAL(18,5)),
        [ProductGUID] = CASE WHEN ProductGUID LIKE Expression + '%' OR ProductGUID LIKE '{' + Expression + '}' THEN CAST(ProductGUID AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) END,
        [ShortName] = n.x.value('ShortName[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM    @XML.nodes('/Products/Product') AS n(x)
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   SELECT  [ProductGUID] = n.x.value('ProductGUID[1]', 'varchar(40)') ,
                    [Expression] = REPLACE('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN 
        ) Expr
```

**EDIT**

I have edited the above query to allow for invalid GUIDs (With a little help from [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12694703/1048425))

If you are using SQL-Server 2012 then you can use [TRY_CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx):

```
SELECT  [AgreementId] = TRY_CONVERT(INT, n.x.value('AgreementId[1]', 'varchar(20)')),
        [Difference] =TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 5), n.x.value('Difference[1]', 'varchar(max)')),
        [DispatchedQuantity] = TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 5), n.x.value('DispatchedQuantity[1]', 'varchar(max)')),
        [Freight] = TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 5), n.x.value('Freight[1]', 'varchar(20)')),
        [ProductGUID] = TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, n.x.value('ProductGUID[1]', 'varchar(40)')),
        [ShortName] = n.x.value('ShortName[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM    @XML.nodes('/Products/Product') AS n(x)
```

Comment: Thanks! the isnumeric test does work. now, what is wrong with the uniqueidentifier? The uniqueidentifier flunks with this: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier... although not always!:-\

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting this trouble with the GUID. I did go back and edit my original SELECT with the extra varchar on the decimal conversion. The first post was just a bad cut and paste job.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
declare @xml xml 

select @xml = '
<Products>
  <Product>
      <AgreementId>2439</AgreementId>
      <Difference>aaa</Difference>
      <DispatchedQuantity>7800.00000</DispatchedQuantity>
      <Freight>0.01560</Freight>
      <ProductGUID>d475165c-0031-41f6-ad44-cecb73dfd2de</ProductGUID>
      <ShortName>U_B5Not Specif_No2_U</ShortName>
    </Product>
  </Products>'

select
    CALC2.Agreement,
    CALC2.[Difference],
    CALC2.DispatchedQuantity,
    CALC2.ProductGUID,
    CALC2.Freight,
    CALC.ShortName
from @xml.nodes('/Products/Product') as n(x)
    outer apply
    (
        select
            isnull(n.x.value('AgreementId[1]', 'varchar(20)'), '0') as Agreement,
            isnull(n.x.value('Difference[1]', 'varchar(20)'), '0.00000') as     [Difference],
            isnull(n.x.value('DispatchedQuantity[1]', 'varchar(20)'), '0.00000') as DispatchedQuantity,
            n.x.value('ProductGUID[1]', 'varchar(40)') as ProductGUID,
            isnull(n.x.value('Freight[1]', 'varchar(20)'), '0.00000') as Freight,
            n.x.value('ShortName[1]', 'varchar(100)') as ShortName
    ) as CALC
    outer apply
    (
        select
            case when CALC.Agreement not like '%[^0-9]%' then cast(CALC.Agreement as int) else null end as Agreement,
            case when CALC.[Difference] not like '%[^0-9]%' then cast(CALC.[Difference] as decimal(18,5)) else null end as [Difference],
            case when CALC.DispatchedQuantity not like '%[^0-9]%' then null else cast(CALC.DispatchedQuantity as decimal(18,5)) end as DispatchedQuantity,
            cast(CALC.ProductGUID as uniqueidentifier) as ProductGUID,
            case when CALC.Freight not like '%[^0-9]%' then null else cast(CALC.Freight as decimal(18,5)) end as Freight
    ) as CALC2
```

Comment: helpful, but fails isnull when some notnull gets tagged.

Comment: I've changed a script. I'm not using isnumeric function because sometimes it's not working properly