# SQL Server 2012 Inline Trap Bad Cast?

Tags: sql-server, casting, guid

I have a bunch of imported data from a text file that needs to be cast to its native GUID. It looks like this:

```
declare @um table ( badtext varchar(36) )
insert into @um values ( '9C7FF2D7-800B-4954-A73A-0BA58B1497AB' )
insert into @um values (  'boom' )
select cast (badtext as uniqueidentifier ) from @um
```

The bad data is already in there, and I need to convert it into '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' if the cast fails. My preference is to do it inline with the rest of a larger Select statement. Playing with IsNull and Cast did not get me anywhere...

How can I cast a bad value inline to something "good"?

Thanks.

EDIT

I think I found that this will work. All comments appreciated.

```
declare @um table ( badtext varchar(36) )
insert into @um values ( '9C7FF2D7-800B-4954-A73A-0BA58B1497AB' )
insert into @um values (  'boom' )
select Cast( IsNull ( try_cast( badtext as UniqueIdentifier ) ,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' ) as uniqueidentifier ) as good from @um
```

Comment: See if this answer helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649317/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-uniqueidentifier

Comment: I think you meant TRY_CONVERT not TRY_CAST