# Remove guids from ntext column

Tags: sql-server, guid, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to update a big amount of data in a customer db, but I've encountered a problem.
The column (ntext) I need to update contains a mix of regular text/comments and guid's.

I only need to update the cells that does NOT contain a GUID.

Searching for ways to determine if some text is a uniqueidentifier/guid in SQL gave multiple solutions like som regex, but for some reason that did not remove all entries of guids from the select statement. (I tried some of the solutions from here: [How to check if a string is a uniqueidentifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649317/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-uniqueidentifier))

Can someone tell me how to remove all kinds of guid'like entries in the ntext column?

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Example of guid removed correctly:

4cfb5539-1656-4447-87f7-ea7c4ea94e96

Example f guid still in the list:

f5f284a0-c1c5-4c71-95b6-1eaa3ed38222

They're the same length, I don't see any hidden characters or spaces (tried to trim with no difference) etc.

EDIT 2:
The SQL statement I used:
SELECT * from TABLE
where VALUE like 
       REPLACE(REPLACE('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]'),' ','')

EDIT 3:
Another statement removing any whitespace as first step

SELECT * from TABLE
where REPLACE(Convert(nvarchar(max),VALUE), ' ', '') not like 
           REPLACE('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]')

Comment: Can you show what you tried and an example of a GUID that was *not* detected or a text value that was falsely detected as a GUID?

Comment: Thanks - and the SQL you used?

Comment: Added as well, should have thought of that the first time, sorry :)

Comment: The outer `REPLACE` is trimming blanks from the inner `REPLACE`, not from `VALUE` - unless I misread ... does the missed GUID have leading or trailing blanks?

Comment: The missed guids doesnt have any leading or trailing blanks. Copy/paste'ing a missed guid from sql table to notepad++ reveals no extra spaces.

Comment: There's something else going on. Here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6259a/1/0) with your current example data and your EDIT 3 query, and it returns no rows. Could you maybe build up the fiddle to a point where it exhibits the problem you've mentioned?

Comment: This is soooo strange. The fiddle you made (actually never heard of that site, looks neat) is how I would expect the SQL to return, but firing the exact same thing in our SQL server doest behave like that...

Comment: Dumb question, but you don't have any 0's that are actually capital o's do you?

Comment: There's no dumb questions, but no - The "invalid" guids doesn't contain any capital o's insted of 0's :)
I've had several people look at it at the office, but our best solution is to try and make a quick .net program instead of using SQL....

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE column like '%-%-%-%-%'
```

This filter condition will find all the rows that have a guid in the "column" column.

You could also do something more complex using `PATINDEX`