# How to check if a value in a column is GUID in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column which is of type `nvarchar`, once the row is processed it updates it with a unique identifier. I need to insert the values other than GUID and NULL into a different table. Is there any built in function to determine whether the value in the column is unique identifier?

Comment: We need more info - what sort of values are you storing in this column?  How 'close' are they to the GUIDs you're using?  ... Also, why was this design chosen?  Seems like you're 1) potentially loosing history visibility, and 2) potentially violating good normalization practices by using a column for multiple things.

Comment: Storing different types of data in the same column is a very bad design. Instead of trying to find a hack around this, you'd be better off fixing the design.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand that storing different type of data in the same column is a bad design, but now I don't have an option , as this design is existing in the project for years

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to check it:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE @StringToCompare LIKE REPLACE('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '0', '[0-9a-fA-F]');
```

or you could see this page for more solutions:
[How to check if a string is a uniqueidentifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649317/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-uniqueidentifier)

Comment: 1) The answer in the post where you found this states that this simple substitution will fail in many collations 2) This will force a full table scan, resulting in awful performance

Comment: You are right @Panagiotis Kanavos, I've just simply tested it and not considered more about these problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think There is no such functions, which will determine weather Field is unique / repetitive

only **Primary Key constraints** / Primary Key to the table will (decides / checks) UID or Not-a- UID   .