# How to check if a string is a iOS uniqueidentifier in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How to check if a string is a iOS unique device identifier?

It's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649317/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-uniqueidentifier), except I'm looking for an answer in BigQuery SQL, and preferably in #StandardSQL.

`SELECT something FROM table WHERE IsUniqueidentifier(column) = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
#StandardSQL
WITH data AS
  (SELECT "4CE798CD-D691-44D2-9FFA-EC440256B933" as string
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "597CCBE1-4388-423B-A6A9-03F7276B1861" as string
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "1AC8A2BB-E263-488B-A81C-774B659D7EE5" as string
  union all 
  SELECT "so long and thanks for all the fish" as string)

SELECT
  string AS valid_string
FROM data
  WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(string, r'[0-9a-fA-F]', '0') 
  LIKE '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `regexp_contains()`:

```
where regexp_contains(string, '^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}')
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're choosing regexp_contains? I chose regexp_replace as its visually clear on the format we expect the device_id to take.

Comment: @angsty_robot . . . It just seems more natural to me for fitting a pattern to a string.