# Extract comma separated values from comma separated GUIDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a column in table `T1` named `Categories`, which contains GUIDs in XML. I am able to extract the GUIDs in a comma-separated form using the below query.

```
SELECT
  Row, ID, Name, City,
  Category = STUFF(
    (
      SELECT ',' + t.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') 
      FROM dbo.T1 t1  
      OUTER APPLY t1.Categories.nodes('root/string') as t(c)
      WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
  )
FROM
  dbo.T1 t2
```

I have another table `T2`, which contains the names of the Categories. I now want to use these comma-separated GUIDs to go and fetch their corresponding `Name` from `T2`.

What changes do I need to make in my SELECT statement to write a LEFT OUTER JOIN which takes this comma-separated GUIDs and returns comma-separated names from `T2`.

`T2` looks something like this:

[image: T2 looks something like this]

Comment: Your code is for ms sql server, not for mysql. Pls pay attention to correctly tagging the question as it may lead to answers that are not correct for the product that you actually use.

Comment: I would make a dictionary from table 2 to easily get value.

Comment: @jdweng This is a table from the production.  Any other solution with the existing table will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Dictionary<string, string> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("ID"), y => y.Field<string>("NAME"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would join the category name table *before* concatenating the values to avoid another iteration of splitting and concatenating.

**Sample data**

```
create table xmlData
(
  id int,
  data xml
);

insert into xmlData (id, data) values
(1,'
<root>
  <guid>5d8547aa-e1e7-4f69-88a2-655879531582</guid>
  <guid>78555c5d-e39f-48f3-a148-30161b0fb995</guid>
</root>
'),
(2,'
<root>
  <guid>5d8547aa-e1e7-4f69-88a2-655879531582</guid>
  <guid>f58177f6-63c8-4985-baa8-2db05248f13f</guid>
</root>
'),
(3,'
<root>
  <guid>5d8547aa-e1e7-4f69-88a2-655879531582</guid>
  <guid>d8f9b789-6d60-4688-9d91-c0f8b1df5319</guid>
</root>
');

create table categoryName
(
  guid uniqueidentifier,
  name nvarchar(20)
);

insert into categoryName (guid, name) values
('5d8547aa-e1e7-4f69-88a2-655879531582', 'Alpha'),
('78555c5d-e39f-48f3-a148-30161b0fb995', 'Beta'),
('f58177f6-63c8-4985-baa8-2db05248f13f', 'Gamma'),
('d8f9b789-6d60-4688-9d91-c0f8b1df5319', 'Delta');
```

**Solution**

Two versions because the SQL Server version is not specified in the question tags... The `string_agg()` function is available starting from SQL Server 2017.

*With `string_agg()`*

```
select xd.id,
       string_agg(cn.name, ',') as 'category_names'
from xmlData xd
cross apply xd.data.nodes('root/guid') g(guid)
join categoryName cn
  on cn.guid = g.guid.value('.', 'nvarchar(36)')
group by xd.id
order by xd.id;
```

*Without `string_agg()`*

```
select xd.id,
       stuff( ( select ',' + cn.name
                from xmlData xd2
                cross apply xd.data.nodes('root/guid') g(guid)
                join categoryName cn
                  on cn.guid = g.guid.value('.', 'nvarchar(36)')
                where xd2.id = xd.id
                for xml path('') ), 1, 1, '' ) as 'category_names'
from xmlData xd
order by xd.id;
```

**Result**

```
id  category_names
--  --------------
1   Alpha,Beta
2   Alpha,Gamma
3   Alpha,Delta
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be5ed8bcd1917ddfd3e41ba392e48015) to see things in action.

Comment: This works fine in DbFiddle. But when running in SSMS. It gives the following error "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier." Is this due to the fact that in some places the CategoryName is NULL. The CategoryName can be NULL. How to handle this ?
PS : There are many other columns in the table. So the CategoryNAme is allowed to be Null.

Comment: It is not related to a category name being `null` ([proof](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=78974c64fbd08b22ec36863a74687366)). It appears that your XML contains a non-guid value where you expect it and the conversion fails. Write a query to validate your XML ([hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649317/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-uniqueidentifier)).

Comment: This is what the xml looks like
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2006/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2006/XMLSchema-instance">
  <string>cdd49ab6-00d9-c268-07c5-0b404aad7315</string>
</ArrayOfString>

Comment: Is the error a remnant of your initial solution with `outer apply` (my solution uses `cross apply` and filters out empty guid's)? I cannot reproduce your issue ([reproduction attempt](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e80f8759edc496cc946580167e22aece)). If the issue persists, then please post a _new question_ with (1) data model, (2) sample data and (3) your current query to provide us with a complete [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).