# How to get all hex strings from table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following data sample from a string (VARCHAR) column of my database;

```
05132029637536
05132029485505
b9bd3841e7dc4996b203403fc023dd72
05132067164110
05132029637535
05132029637559
05132029485490
05132029637522
05132029485475
42cdeaf2a9864486a6548dc7a580e7c7
05132029485494
05132029485477
```

Note that in my case, this column is filled with all kinds of strings, some are numbers like above, but also string like `Hello2133.231` or similar exists (i don't have samples handy).

Some of the rows are a hex code string.

How can I query all hex code strings with good precision?

Comment: Your sampledata could be a coincidence, but if it is guids you are looking for, then there is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649317/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-uniqueidentifier

Comment: Is `DeadBeef` a string or a hexadecimal value?  `Facade`?  Any of the other [magic debug values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values)? Do you need the resulting integer value or do you only need to identify strings built from a limited character set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return everything tha can be interpreted as hex:
`select * from yourtable where trim(yourcolumn) not like '%[^0-9a-f]%'`

Of course, this will also return the other rows you meantioned, since there is no way to tell `05132029637536` is hex or not.

If you go down the rabbit hole and assume a string is hex only when (you're lucky enough that) it has at least a letter, you could additionally filter:
`and trim(yourcolumn) like '%[a-f]%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with like but there is possibility to select non hex n

```
Select colname from table1 
where colname LIKE '%[^0-9A-F]%'
```